# Compass/SASS creates files I cannot change

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, ubuntu-12.04, compass-sass

Today I was working on my website using Compass/SASS. No idea why, but all of a sudden when I try to run `sudo compass create` now, it creates the necessary files and directories, but with a lock on them so I can't change them. I have tried the following, with all of the steps working, but the end effect remains the same:

- Deleting the visible files and recreating them
- Deleting the visible and invisible files with command line `sudo rm -rf [file/directory name]`, also cleaning the sass cache
- Reinstalling compass and sass
- Reinstalling compass and sass after purging ruby and ruby gems

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Hope you guys can help me.

Ivor

Comment: I'm not familiar with compass, but if you are creating files using `sudo`, they will be owned by root and not writable as a regular user.

Comment: You shouldn't be using sudo. Did you install the compass gem via sudo?

Comment: @andHapp Installing gems usually requires sudo (at least in my experience), but running Compass does not.

Comment: @cimmanon Depends on your set-up, but it doesn't have to be that way.

Comment: I tried installing the necessary programs without sudo, but that wasn't possible. And the strange thing is that I used the sudo command before with compass, but it did not result in a lock on the files and directories.